# How to add an element to list in scala?

Tags: scala, list

I am trying to add an element to a range in scala. Why does the following code snippet fail? What's the right way to do it?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val range = Range(1, 10)
val buffer = ListBuffer()
buffer.appendAll(range)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't informed the compiler what type elements `buffer` will hold.

```
val buffer = ListBuffer[Int]()
```

After that the `appendAll()` should work fine. But there's nothing in your code that will "add an element to a range" (or a list, as the question title falsely indicates). That's a different operation.

You can pre-pend or append a new element but you get an `IndexedSeq[Int]` back.

```
0 +: range
range :+ 14
```

If you want a real `Range` you can build a new one.

```
val biggerRange = Range(range.start - 1 , range.end + 2, range.step)
```

Answer (score -1):

ListBuffer appenAll need traversable object.
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html

Workaround is to use -

```
val buffer = ListBuffer[Int]()
for (i <- range ) buffer.append(i)
```